# File watcher to check and sleep if file does not exist, Unix

Tags: python

```
import os.path
import os
import glob
import time

list_dir ='/path/to/file'
os.chdir(list_dir)
FILE_NAME = glob.glob('XXX_XXXX_o000000375*')
path_to_files = glob.glob( os.path.join(list_dir, 'XXX_XXXX_o000000375*'))


if ( not os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME)):
    print("error: %s file not found" % FILE_NAME)
else:
    print("Setting WAGs jail using %s ..." % FILE_NAME)
```

Im new to this and Im trying to create a script to look for a file and if one is not present then to sleep and try again.  When I run it I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File
    "createfile.py", line 20, in <module>
        if ( not os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME)):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 29, in isfile
        st = os.stat(path) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Can someone please help me with my issue?

Comment: reading the error would be a good start. isfile() expects a string (e.g. filename) and you're passing in the list you got from glob().

Answer (score 1):

`FILE_NAME` is not a file, it's a list of path's and that's because you use `glog.glob()` as indicated [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

> **glob.glob(pathname)**
>
> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).

Comment: If I need to use a wildcard because the date and time changes daily and the time is not always the same time, then how can I have it look for the file?